Как ловить исключение PSQLException
У меня используется Spring boot JDBCTemplate и он может выдать исключение PSQLException используя try catch на методы как query
получаю это сообщение от Idea Exception 'org.postgresql.util.PSQLException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block я посмотрел документацию методы которые я использую они могут выкинуть только DataAccessException но я могу получить и PSQLException если креды не правильные
Пример кода
     try {
         return template.queryForObject(
                    sql,
                    (rs, i) -> new Result()
                        .setType1(rs.getType1(1))
                        .setType2(rs.getType2(2)),
                    params);
        } catch (PSQLException e){
         //обработка 
        }catch (DataAccessException e) {
         //обработка 
        }


Если idea пишет что не выбрасывается, значит так и есть. Скиньте фрагмент кода
